# upload with meteor and dropbox

Tags: meteor, file-upload, dropbox-api, collectionfs

I'm trying to do an upload using dropbox, but something is going wrong and I don't know what it is. I've done some searches on the Internet and I couldn't find anything.

Here it's my code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.helpers({
    uploads:function(){
      return Avatars.find();
    },
    images:function(){
      return Images.find();
    }
  });

  var avatarStoreLarge = new FS.Store.Dropbox("avatarsLarge");
  var avatarStoreSmall = new FS.Store.Dropbox("avatarsSmall");

  Avatars = new FS.Collection("avatars", {
    stores: [avatarStoreSmall, avatarStoreLarge],
    filter: {
      allow: {
        contentTypes: ['image/*']
      }
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
   'change .fileInput':function(event,template){
     FS.Utility.eachFile(event,function(file){
       var fileObj = new FS.File(file);
       Avatars.insert(fileObj,function(err){
         console.log(err);
       })
     })
   }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    var avatarStoreLarge = new FS.Store.Dropbox("avatarsLarge", {
      key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
      secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
      token: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
      transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
        gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('250', '250').stream().pipe(writeStream)
      }
    })

    var avatarStoreSmall = new FS.Store.Dropbox("avatarsSmall", {
      key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
      secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
      token: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      beforeWrite: function(fileObj) {
        fileObj.size(20, {store: "avatarStoreSmall", save: false});
      },
      transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
        gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('20', '20').stream().pipe(writeStream)
      }
    })

    Avatars = new FS.Collection("avatars", {
      stores: [avatarStoreSmall, avatarStoreLarge],
      filter: {
        allow: {
          contentTypes: ['image/*']
        }
      }
    })
  });
}
```

I did this example following [this documentation.](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/tree/master/packages/dropbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, check installed meteor packages: `meteor list`, to get code to work you have to install:

```
cfs:standard-packages
cfs:dropbox
```

**Second**, simplify your code to reduce error precursors (Example in docs [required](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#image-manipulation) Image Manipulation packages), for example: 
*CLIENT-SIDE*

```
var dataStorage = new FS.Store.Dropbox("imageData");

Images = new FS.Collection("imageData", {
    stores: [dataStorage],
    filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*']
            }
        }
    });
```

Template.helpers block

```
'imageToShow': function(){
    return Images.find()
    },
```

Template.events block

```
'click #imageToUpload': function(event, template) {
            FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
                Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {});
                });
            },
```

*SERVER-SIDE*

```
var dataStorage = new FS.Store.Dropbox("imageData", {
    key: "...",
    secret: "...",
    token: "..."
    });

Images = new FS.Collection("imageData", {
    stores: [dataStorage],
    filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*']
            }
        }
    });
```

**Third**, handle errors to figure out what's going wrong.

**Fourth**, it takes time to upload and download back images from dropbox, to test your app use light weighted files. Use `console.log` in client and server sides to see apps' flow.

Answer (score 0):

First check if you have installed the following packages:

```
cfs:standard-packages
cfs:dropbox
cfs:gridfs
```

Install them:

```
meteor add cfs:standard-packages
meteor add cfs:dropbox
meteor add cfs:gridfs
```

Make sure your file **"client/collections_client/avatar.js"** looks like this:

```
Template.hello.helpers({
  'imageToShow': function(){
      return Images.find()
      },
});

var dataStorage = new FS.Store.Dropbox("imageData");

Images = new FS.Collection("imageData", {
    stores: [dataStorage],
    filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*']
            }
        }
    });

Template.hello.events({
  'click #imageToUpload': function(event, template) {
             FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
                 Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {});
                 });
             },
});
```

**"client/collections_client/hello.html"**

```
<template name="hello">
  <input type="file" name="teste" id="imageToUpload">
</template>

<body>
{{> hello}}
</body>
```

Assuming you have [created your app](https://www.dropbox.com/developers):

**"server/collections_server/avatar.js"**

```
var dataStorage = new FS.Store.Dropbox("imageData", {
    key: "yourAppKey",
    secret: "yourAppSecret",
    token: "youroAuth2Token"
    });

Images = new FS.Collection("imageData", {
    stores: [dataStorage]
    });
```